# Check if a string list contains any substrings from another string list

Tags: linq

There are similar questions out there on how to check if a string contains any inputs on a list, but I am confused on how to do this for two list of strings.

Suppose I have a first List containing:

```
["five", "four", "three", "two", "one"]
```

and have a second `List<string>` containing:

```
["bathroom", "twelve", "thirteen", "fou"]
```

I want to see if any of the "substrings" within List 2 match with List 1. If any of the substrings in List 2 are found in List 1 (i.e. "fou") it is true, otherwise if there are no substring matches found it is false.

I'd imagine this would use linq but I am unsure how to do this for two string lists.

Comment: It would help to put a tag or mention in your question the language that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list1.Any(s1 => list2.Any(s2 => s1.Contains(s2)));
```

or, using more tricky syntax

```
var result = list1.Any(s1 => list2.Any(s1.Contains));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have just `bool result` - if any `string` (say, `"fou"`) within `secondList` contains in any item within `firstList` (say, `four`: **fou**r) -
you can try

```
  List<string> firstList = new List<string>() {
    "five", "four", "three", "two", "one",
  };

  List<string> secondList = new List<string>() {
    "bathroom", "twelve", "thirteen", "fou",
  };  

  ...

  bool result = secondList
    .Any(second => firstList.Any(first => first.Contains(second)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "five", "four", "three", "two", "one" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "bathroom", "twelve", "thirteen", "fou" };
var found = list1.Any(i1 => list2.Any(i2 => i1.Contains(i2)));
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, I understand that you are having trouble debugging. You can extend the above code like for example below, so it helps you better understand what the code is doing:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "five", "four", "three", "two", "one" };
var list2 = new List<string> {  "f", "o", "t" };
var found = list1.All(i1 =>
    { 
        var l1Result = list2.Any(i2 => 
            {
                var l2Reuslt = i1.Contains(i2);
                Console.WriteLine($"{i1} constains {i2}: {l2Reuslt}");
                return l2Reuslt;
            });
        Console.WriteLine($"{i1} Final : {l1Result}");
        return l1Result;
    }
);
```

Comment: If you were to use All instead, would you just replace?

Comment: @Berek i don't understand your question.

Comment: @Berek try it out yourself? ;-)

Comment: If you replace both any with All then it means that all of list 1 needs to have all of list 2 containing.  if you do list1.All / list2.Any means all of list1 needs at least one matching item in list 2...